# Replacing counter with a function

Tags: iteration, counting, modular-arithmetic

Let `n` be an odd number. Suppose we have the sequence `s:=n,n+2,n+4,⋯`. The goal is to associate this sequence with two other sequences, `a` and `b`. I will show how `a` and `b` are related to the original sequence with an example:

[image]

Both `a` and `b` act as some sort of a "counter": `a` counts from `0` to `n−1` and resets back to `0` if it equals `n`. `b` starts from `1` and increases by `2` every time `a` resets.

---

Instead of having to depend on the previous values, I wish to find these counters as a function of `s` and `n` only.

As we notice, the sequence `a` is very similar to modulo, with a slight modification, i.e.,

[image]

Can `b` be found as a function `f(s,n)` too? I suspect that this would involve the quotients of `s` but I could not come up with any.

Comment: If you can find out how many "cycles" `a` has gone through, then `b` is just that amount, times 2, plus 1.

Comment: @Alexander thats correct but youre not allowed to maintain a cycle count! Also working with ```a``` is the same as working with ```s``` since we already established it as a function of ```s``` and ```n```

Comment: There's a closed form for the cycle count, which is similar to the formula you already got for `a`. Instead of `a = s * ((1+n) / 2) % n`, replace modulo with division: `cycleCountOf(a) = s * ((1+n) / 2) / n`

Comment: @Alexander wouldnt that yield fractional values

Comment: not with integer division, which is the standard in most languages